# Transitivity-related property of finite permutation groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-groups

Let $\cal F$ denote the group of all finitely-supported permutations of $\mathbb N$.
   Say that a finite subgroup $G$ of $\cal F$ is singular if $G$ acts transitively on
$\lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$ but no cyclic subgroup
of $G$  acts transitively on    $\lbrace 1,2,3 \rbrace$ (this is equivalent
to saying that some element in $G$ sends $1$ to $2$, another sends $1$ to $3$
but no element of $G$ has all of $1,2$ and $3$ in a single orbit).

The Klein group (products of disjoint transpositions on $\lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$)
is in example of such a subgroup.

Question 1 : are there other simple examples of minimal singular subgroups ?
Is there a parametric description of all of them up to isomorphism ?

Question 2 : Denote by ${\cal F}(i \to j)$ the set of all permutations in $\cal F$
sending $i$ to $j$. Say that a permutation $s\in {\cal F}(1 \to 2)$
and a permutation $t\in {\cal F}(1 \to 3)$ are related iff
the subgroup generated by $s$ and $t$ is a minimal singular subgroup of $\cal F$.
Given $s$, let $R(s)$ denoted the set of all $t$'s such that $s$ and $t$ are related.
Does $R(s)$ admit a simple description ?

Of course, any answer to question 2 automatically provides an answer to
question 1.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example for Q1 generalizing your example for the Klein group:

Let $G$ be any *non-cyclic* finite group generated by two elements $g$ and $h$. Take the regular action of $G$ on itself, i.e., let $G$ act on itself by right rsp. left multiplication. Identify $G$ (as set acted upon) with a subset of $\mathbb N$ where the $1$ of the group is identified with $1 \in \mathbb N$, $g$ is identified with $2$ and $h$ with $3$.

As the orbits of the cyclic subgroups of $G$ containing $1$ are just the cyclic subgroups, none of them containing both $g$ and $h$,  $G$ considered as subgroup (the regular action is faithful) of $\cal F$ is *minimal singular*.

Probably the condition *minimal singular* is too weak to be helpful. By the way, "finitely-supported" permutations are often called *finitary*.